# Jquery Multiple elements-Multiple events - Same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have not found any answer. So asking.

**My HTML code**

```
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

**My JS**

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
$("#mySelect").on("change", function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

So in both events my function do the same thing. How can I combine these two events and type my function there? Is it possible?

I heard about **trigger**. I can use that. But want to know if there is any way to merge these events.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ECWM5/)

Comment: use a referenced function for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use one function, and reference it in the event handlers

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function_name);
$("#mySelect").on("change", function_name);


function function_name() {
    // code for both handlers goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript function

```
  <script>
    function clickme(){
    alert("Hi");
    }
    </script>    

<button id="myButton" onclick="clickme()">Click Me</button>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="clickme()">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
```